# Where can I ask a question about penetration testing labs?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask this question:

> Are there free online penetration testing labs that I can safely hack with my computer?

Is there any site on the Stack Exchange network where I can ask this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asking for off-site resources is, generally speaking, not a good idea on a Q&A site. Those kind of questions are bound to attract opinionated answers and spam, and are therefore likely to be closed.

That said, the Stack Exchange site dealing with these kind of topics is [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to read their [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question.